# Replace RegEx matches

Tags: bash, unix, shell

I have a string like this : `'MDP_44' => 'sdDSD4343khjkjhkjhjk',`

I want to run a function which return only: `MDP_44`.

I tried things like :

```
$ variable=     'MDP_44' => 'sdDSD4343khjkjhkjhjk',
$ echo ${var1//[^A-Z]}     // MDPDSD
```

But the result is not good.

Can someone help me to get `MDP_44`as the result ? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think your variable definition syntax is correct.

Comment: @Mu Qiao : yes you right, it's `variable="     'MDP_44' => 'sdDSD4343khjkjhkjhjk',"`

Comment: You cannot have a space after the equals sign, anf you need to quote or escape the value. And of course, you need to use the same variable name in order to access its value. (^:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var="'MDP_44' => 'sdDSD4343khjkjhkjhjk',"
echo $var | cut -d= -f1 | sed "s/'//g"
```

**EDIT**

or even shorter

```
echo $var | cut -d\' -f2
```

Comment: The first answer is not good because it don't remove spaces. The second answer is good. You are the first to respond so i accept you answer many thanks !

Answer (score 1):

if your variable is:

```
variable="'MDP_44' => 'sdDSD4343khjkjhkjhjk',"
```

then you can use bash **extended pattern matching**:

```
echo ${variable//?(\'| =>*)}
```

Note you need to enable extglob by `shopt -s extglob`, it's enabled by default in interactive mode.

Answer (score 0):

This will extract the first thing in `'`...`'`

```
echo "$variable" | cut -d\' -f2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all from `=>` onwards

```
echo "${variable%%=>*}"
```

Answer (score 0):

using bash regular expressions to find the text between the first set of single quotes.

```
if [[ "$variable" =~ [\']([^\']+) ]]; then match=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; fi
```